# How to define a new method inside an existing class and add a call to it in an existing method inside the same class using bytebuddy?

Tags: java, byte-buddy

I have a class which looks like below

```
public class HelloWorld{
  public void sayHelloWorld(){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

Now I would like to add another method to the **HelloWorld** class using bytebuddy and add a call to the new method in **sayHelloWorld**. So hypothetically the class would look like this after bytebuddy does it's magic. (I know that bytebuddy works with bytecode and not java source files. The below code is just for illustration purpose.)

```
public class HelloWorld{
  public void sayHelloWorld(){
    System.out.println("Hello World");
    sayHelloAgain()
  }
  public void sayHelloAgain(){
    System.out.println("Hello Again")
  }
}
```

1. Firstly, is this possible with bytebuddy?
2. Secondly, if it is possible, how can I do it? I have understood that bytebuddy can be used to redefine methods, but not modify the method body. Is this true?

It would be great if someone could shed some light on this. TIA!

Comment: 1) you need what they call rebasing (http://bytebuddy.net/javadoc/1.7.5/net/bytebuddy/ByteBuddy.html#rebase-java.lang.Class- ) 2) check their tutorial (http://bytebuddy.net/#/tutorial ), section "Redefining and rebasing existing classes" says you use the same syntax as for subclassing (which they discuss in detail), except for the starting point which is the previously mentioned .rebase method. However, modifying an existing method does not seem to be possible, it is only about modifying an existing class I think. Replacing is possible however, but then you have to re-build the complete method

Comment: Thank you. But replacing the entire method body is not an option for me since I would just have access to the bytecode and manipulating bytecode is quite hard and I would like to have a cleaner and easier way of modifying methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Byte Buddy allows you to do this in various ways. The most straight forward way would be to define an interceptor that implements `sayHelloAgain` to which Byte Buddy creates a delegation:

```
public class HelloAgainDelegate {
  public static void sayHelloAgain() {
    System.out.println("Hello again");
  }
}
```

You can then define the method on the redefined class and rebase the `sayHelloWorld` method to first invoke the original method and then invoke the other method:

```
Class<?> type = new ByteBuddy()
  .rebase(HelloWorld.class)
  .defineMethod("sayHelloAgain", void.class, Visibility.PUBLIC)
  .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(HelloAgainDelegate.class))
  .method(named("sayHelloWorld"))
  .intercept(SuperMethodCall.INSTANCE
    .andThen(MethodCall.invoke(named("sayHelloAgain"))))
  .make()
  .load(HelloWorld.class.getClassLoader(), 
        ClassLoadingStrategy.Default.CHILD_FIRST)
  .getLoaded();

Object instance = type.newInstance();
type.getMethod("sayHelloWorld").invoke(instance);
type.getMethod("sayHelloAgain").invoke(instance);
```

In Java code, the rebased class would look something like this:

```
public class HelloWorld {
  synthetic void sayHelloWorld$origin() {
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }  

  public void sayHelloWorld() {
    sayHelloWorld$origin();
    sayHelloAgain();
  }

  public void sayHelloAgain() {
    HelloAgainInterceptor.sayHelloAgain();
  }
}
```

If this delegation is not an option for you, you can also use `Advice` to inline the code from a template class:

```
class HelloAgainAdvice {
  @Advice.OnMethodExit
  static void sayHelloAgain() {
    System.out.println("Hello again");
  }
}
```

Instead of the `MethodDelegation`, you would use this class via `Advice.to(HelloAgainAdvice.class)`. As the code is copied, you will not be able to set break points but your redefined class will be self-contained.